# Rebind DropDownList to value field after filtering

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-dropdown

After filtering then unfiltering a kendo dropdownlist, the view model retains the originally selected value, but the dropdownlist has an empty string for its value.

Is this expected behavior for the dropdownlist? I'd expect the widget to stay in sync with its model. How can I "rebind" the dropdownlist, so it gets the value from its view model after filtering?

```js
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    selectedProduct: null,
    products: [
        { id: 1, name: "Coffee" },
        { id: 2, name: "Tea" },
        { id: 3, name: "Juice" }
    ]
});

kendo.bind($("#dropdown"), viewModel);

var ddl = $("#dropdown").getKendoDropDownList();

console.log("viewModel.selectedProduct.id: " + viewModel.selectedProduct.id + ", ddl.value(): " + ddl.value());

ddl.dataSource.filter({field: "id", value: 4});
ddl.dataSource.filter({});

console.log("viewModel.selectedProduct.id: " + viewModel.selectedProduct.id + ", ddl.value(): " + ddl.value());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<select id="dropdown" data-role="dropdownlist" data-option-label="Select product..."
  data-value-field="id" data-text-field="name" data-bind="value: selectedProduct, source: products">
</select>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to rebind the value. It depends on some undocumented Kendo stuff though, so I'd still prefer another way.

```
var binding = ddl.element.get(0).kendoBindingTarget.toDestroy[0].bindings.value;
var value = binding.source.get(binding.path);
if (value) {
    ddl.value(value.get(ddl.options.dataValueField));
}
```